tile-join is not displaying older tiles at higher zoom levels
I use tippecanoe to convert geojson file to pbf tiles using this command
tippecanoe -e output_dir -zg -Z10 --drop-densest-as-needed --no-tile-compression --extend-zooms-if-still-dropping -l features files.geojson

I have another set of tiles that I want to merge the output_dir with,
tile-join -o merged_file.mbtiles --layer=features --no-tile-size-limit  --no-tile-compression local_gcs_tiles_dir/ output_dir/

I convert the .mbtiles convert back to pbf tiles using mbutil
mbutil/mb-util  --image_format=pbf merged_file.mbtiles output_merged_dir

The new tiles that are generated are available at all zoom levels, but the old tiles are only available at lower zoom levels.
How can I have the older tiles at all zoom levels?

Try adding the --overzoom argument to your tile-join command. This should scale up your old tiles to match the zoom of the new tiles.
I would also recommend replacing -o merged_file.mbtiles with -e output_merged_dir. This will write the merged tiles directly to pbf and let you skip the mbutil command.
From https://github.com/felt/tippecanoe?tab=readme-ov-file#overzooming

--overzoom: If one of the source tilesets has a larger maxzoom than the others, scale up tiles from the tilesets with the lower maxzooms so they will all have the same maxzoom in the output tileset.

